# Simplifying subtemplates that use 'getpart' parameter to speed up OpenTBS

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

As a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573228/prevent-word-2010-from-saving-ogfxdata-base64-or-uuencoded-vml/14594215), I am trying to really simplify several `xml` templates extracted from `.docx` files created in Word 2010 and used as subtemplates in OpenTBS in order to speed up my document creation. The subtemplates contain an `mc:AlternateContent` block which is all I use in my main template, like this:

```
[LineItem.template;block=w:r;file='templates/[val].xml';getpart=(mc:AlternateContent)]
```

I noticed that multiple (20) large (>100KB) subtemplates can seriously affect OpenTBS' speed, so I would like to eliminate the code I am not using (outside of mc:AlternateContent). I am already planning on doing other processing on my templates through TBS and caching the simplified version, so it would be great if I could use OpenTBS' getpart functionality to pull this data from the larger template at the same time. Is this possible?

For instance, to be able to fit this (pseudo-) code into my processing:

```
foreach($templates as $template){ //loop through xml templates
    $TBS->LoadTemplate($template);
    $simpleTemplate = $template->getpart('mc:AlternateContent'); 
    /* 
    / simpleTemplate now holds all the xml inside the mc:AlternateContent tags
    / (everything that would have been included in my template had I used attribute
    / getpart=(mc:AlternateContent) in my file inclusion) 
    */
    $simpleTemplate->save('simple/'.$template);
}
```

*P.S. Should I be asking this on [the TBS forum](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/forum.php) instead?*

Comment: "to pull this data from the larger template at the same time" => what do you mean ? Can you give more precision ?  "P.S. Should I be asking this on the TBS forum instead?" => as you wish, both are ok.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I have added some pseudo code I hope will explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two solutions to extract an XML element from set of files (which are TBS sub-templates).

1)

TBS has a documented method that enables you to get the source code of a TBS block, with or without the TBS fields that define the block.

See [$TBS->GetBlockSource()](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#php_getblocksource)

You can use this method if you already have a TBS block for that part, or if it is possible for you to create a dedicated block in your sub-template.

2)

Otherwise, you can use an undocumented class `clsTbsXmlLoc` provided with OpenTBS:

```
foreach ($templates as $template) {
   $contents = file_get_contents($template);
   $x = clsTbsXmlLoc::FindElement($contents, 'mc:AlternateContent', 0);
   if ($x) {
      $src = $x->GetSrc();
      // use $x->GetInnerSrc() in order to get the content of <mc:AlternateContent>
      // but wihtout the <mc:AlternateContent> tags.
      file_put_contents('simple/'.$template);
   } else {
      echo "Element no found in sub-template $template";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to add a unique block definition to each of my subtemplates and use the $TBS->GetBlockSource method easily. Now my subtemplates are each ~100KB less than they were, and my test cases run about 3 times faster now. Thank you very much!